# Why can't I call load() on a variable?

Tags: empirical-lang

I can call `load()` in the REPL.

```
>>> load("trades.csv")
 symbol                  timestamp    price size
   AAPL 2019-05-01 09:30:00.578802 210.5200  780
   AAPL 2019-05-01 09:30:00.580485 210.8100  390
    BAC 2019-05-01 09:30:00.629205  30.2500  510
    CVX 2019-05-01 09:30:00.944122 117.8000 5860
   AAPL 2019-05-01 09:30:01.002405 211.1300  320
   AAPL 2019-05-01 09:30:01.066917 211.1186  310
   AAPL 2019-05-01 09:30:01.118968 211.0000  730
    BAC 2019-05-01 09:30:01.186416  30.2450  380
    ...                        ...      ...  ...
```

But I can't load a command-line argument in a script:

```
let trades = load(argv[1])
```

I get an error:

```
Error: macro parameter filename requires a comptime literal
Error: unable to determine type for trades
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Empirical is statically typed. `load()` will infer a Dataframe's type if the file path can be determined at compile time. Variables and arbitrary expressions are permitted. For example:

```
let filename = "trades.csv"
let trades = load("./" + filename)
```

The `filename` above is a constant (immutable) because it was declared with `let`. But `argv` is mutable (not constant) because it is implicitly declared with `var`.

Empirical must know the type of the Dataframe, which we will have to pass explicitly in this case. Fortunately, we can get a hint in the REPL.

```
>>> columns(load("trades.csv"))
symbol: String
timestamp: Timestamp
price: Float64
size: Int64
```

We will also have to call `csv_load()` instead, since that takes a template. Here is the script as it should be:

```
data Trade:
  symbol: String,
  timestamp: Timestamp,
  price: Float64,
  size: Int64
end

let trades = csv_load{Trade}(argv[1])
```

This compiles as expected. Calling `print(trades)` in the script will display the Dataframe.